# cordova ios device ready not fire until tap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I use cordova regular on ubuntu for android.

I compile with build.phonegap.com for ios, uploading zip project.

with Android all fine, but with ios deviceready not fire until i tap or change the focus to other thing.

Mi index is simple:

```
  <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
        content="
        default-src  'self' https://ssl.gstatic.com data:* gap://* file://* tel:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ;
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        frame-src  'self'  s-static.ak.facebook.com static.ak.facebook.com www.facebook.com;
        connect-src 'self' https://app.mypage.es/ connect.facebook.net www.facebook.com; 
        media-src *;
        img-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com www.facebook.com;
        script-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' www.google-analytics.com connect.facebook.net www.facebook.com">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fastclick.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

and the index.js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {....stuff}
```

i try diferent alternatives to content-policy and diferent ways to atach event

What is the correct way?

Comment: I achieve debug with weinre and it find: 
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally removing all platforms and plugins, and adding them after, solve my problems.

have you tried restarting?